# Extract string before specific character

Tags: python

i have list of images , which are  named  as follow :
Abyssinian_1.jpg

so name_digit.jpg

of course if it would be only one _digit.jpg, then using split statement  it is very  easy,but whe have also image named as follow

```
Egyptian_Mau_214.jpg
```

sure  we should  extract  text before _digit, but i am not sure which regular  expression method can i  use for it?i will demonstrate one example

let us suppose we have following string :

```
name ='Egyptian_Mau_214.jpg'
```

if i use split statement

```
print(name.split("_"))
```

then result would be : `['Egyptian', 'Mau', '214.jpg']`
but i want to split  before the _214, so how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would this work:

```
name ='Egyptian_Mau_214.jpg'

m = re.split(r'_(?=\d+\.[a-z]+$)', name)

print(m) # ['Egyptian_Mau', '214.jpg']
```

Comment: so m[0] will be only string right

Answer (score 1):

Hope I got it right, but you could use a regex.
For your example:

```py
import re
r = re.compile('(.+)_(\d+\.jpg)')
m = r.match('Egyptian_Mau_214.jpg')
print(m.groups()) # -> ('Egyptian_Mau', '214.jpg')
```

Regex explanation:

1. `(.+)` - Group 1, 1 or more of any character.
2. `_` - Just an underscore.
3. `(\d+\.jpg)` - Group 2, one or more digits, and `.jpg` suffix.